# VS 2015 Debug method being tested

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm developing a unit test, and I'm getting a null ref exception. I would like to debug not only the code of the test, but the real method being tested... how can i do that?
right now, if I F11 the method, i just get the exception...

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: @LexLi I figured the F11 reference in OP's question suggests he's already doing that...

Comment: Put a break point early in the method being tested so that it can be caught before what ever is throwing the exception. You may need to show some code to provide some context.

Comment: You would debug that as any regular code... There are plenty of questions about NRE and general way of breaking on exception. You've clearly already looked at those - but it makes unclear what exactly you need help with.